# Q：When I add UIScrollView to a UIView, but the scrollView can not scroll

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I add a `UIScrollView` to a customView, and I set the right `contentSize`, but the scrollView can not scroll.

This is my code:

```
_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - 44)];
//    _scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
//    _scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;



_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(3 * self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - 44 + 500);

_scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake((_orginSelectedIndex)*(self.bounds.size.width), 44);

_scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

_scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

[self addSubview:_scrollView];

/* add tableviews */
for (int i = 0 ; i < _titlesArr.count; i ++) {

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * self.bounds.size.width, 44, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height - 44) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableView.tag = 200 + i;
    tableView.backgroundColor = RandColor;
    [self addSubview:tableView];
}
```

And I also Log my scroll's `contentSize`.

```
 NSLog(@"%@-s", NSStringFromCGSize(lml_pager.scrollView.contentSize));
```

There show :

```
2016-06-21 17:39:07.272 LMLViewPager[7381:312567] {1125, 1059}-s
```

Somebody know what the issue is? I did not use autolayout in my code.

And there is my picture token in the debug:
Obviously,it only add one `tableView`, my `_titlesArr` count is 3.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PGuK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tableview should be added to scrollview instead of scrollview's superview.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have user interaction turned on as well.

Comment: The view and scrollview's userInteractionEnabled = YES;

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `UITableView` on top of the `UIScrollView` which actually put the the scrollView below the tableView. If you want the tableView to be a part of the scrollView. Try to add tableView as subview of the scrollView

Answer (score 0):

Your view hierarchy is like below :

```
YourCustomView->ScrollView->TableView
```

Now you are trying to scroll, scrollview but you can see that `Tableview` is on `top` of hierarchy. So it won't scroll horizontally.

Comment: Thx, my false.U helped me.